# Simple HTML DOM cannot get file

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have no clue what the solution might be.
I simply cannot get the html file of this Charizard, I don't get any response even though the link is correct. Bulbasaur is working fine, but I want this lovely Charizard...

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charizard_(Pok%C3%A9mon)');
$html2 = file_get_html('https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)');
echo $html;
echo $html2;
```

Does this page have any protection or is Charizard only harder to catch?
I'd appreciate if you are able to help me with this.

Jonas :)

Comment: This is a known bug, see https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser/issues/41

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the curl thing. First, I need to understand it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Length of the content fetched from this URL exceeds `MAX_FILE_SIZE` (defined in `simple_html_dom.php`)
2. The bug that was pointed out in the comments (https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser/issues/37). This bug seems to be resolved in the forked repository that is maintained on github but it still exists in [original version](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) (which does not seem to be maintained anymore).

To solve the first problem, edit `simple_html_dom.php` and change `define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);` to use a bigger number.

As a workaround for the second problem, pass correct parameters to `file_get_html`, and by that I mean to pass `0` for `$offset`:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charizard_(Pok%C3%A9mon)',
false,
null,
0); // this last one is the offset

var_dump($html);
```

Alternatively you can use the [forked version of the library](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser).

Comment: I added two zeros to the MAX_FILE_SIZE as well and it's working now!! Thank you so much for this! I should have known that you have to throw an ultra ball to catch Charizard, not just an Pokeball.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest an [alternative library](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom) because II don't think you will get this with simple_html_dom:

```
include 'advanced_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charizard_(Pok%C3%A9mon)');

echo $html->find('h1', 0)->text() . PHP_EOL;
echo $html->find('big a[title*="Pokédex number"]', 0)->text() . PHP_EOL;
```

This gives:

```
Charizard (Pokémon)
#006
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the file size, but your answer is correct, too. I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score -1):

Since i haven't found the `file_get_html()` in the php docs, maybe you prefer using `file_get_contents(url)` instead.

Comment: `file_get_html` is from the `simple_html_dom` class, http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm.

Comment: Oh, yes i didn't noticed about that, my bad. Anyway what i said in the answer should work for get the html from the web @user3783243

Comment: @alex55132 `file_get_html()` uses `file_get_contents()` internally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This gives me the page, but I can't use the find() method, because it seems to be a string. I need to convert it to a html file.